# How to get Img src from a remote webapge

Tags: php

I am trying this code to get all images src from the link (https://www.vfmii.com/exc/aspquery?command=invoke&ipid=HL26423&ids=42337&RM=N)
But it is showing nothing to me. Can you suggest me some better way?

```
<?php
include_once 'simple_html_dom.php';

$html = file_get_html('https://www.vfmii.com/exc/aspquery?command=invoke&ipid=HL26423&ids=42337&RM=N');    
       // Find all images 
foreach($html->find('img') as $element) { 

        echo $element->src. "<br>";

}
?>
```

Comment: There are no image tags in that document source, its all client side compilation.

Answer (score 2):

Content is loaded using XHR. But you can get the JSON :

```
$js = file_get_contents('https://www.vfmii.com/exc/aspquery?command=invoke&ipid=HL26423&ids=42337&RM=N&out=json&lang=en');
$json = substr($js,8,-2) ;
$data = json_decode($json, true);
// print_r(array_keys($data)) ;


// example :
foreach ($data['rcoData'] as $rcoData) {
    if (isset($rcoData['encodings'])) {
        $last = end($rcoData['encodings'])['url'] ;
        echo $last ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The website in question that you're trying to scrape has content that is loaded through javascript after load. "PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser" can only get content that is on the page statically on load.